# How to search for JavaScript variables in a file, using Python?

Tags: javascript, python

I have directory with many JaveScript files. Here I want to scan each file and want to replace each JavaScript variable with string like `'str1'`, `'str2'`, `'str3'`, ..., `'strn'` and so on.

My question is: how to identify a JavaScript variable?

Doubts:

1. If I say keyword after `var` is a variable, however there is no compulsion of `var` while declaring variable
2. If I say keyword before `=` is a variable, however file also contains HTML code, so inside HTML tag there is `=` sign between attribute and its value.

So how can I identify the variables I have to replace?

Comment: I'm not a regex wizard but this might be doable for one of them

Comment: perhaps to build a list to store all the keywords you get from regex before `=` and after `var`, and check keywords from there on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for a JavaScript parser. [slimit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit) is a Python package that will allow you to parse JavaScript code and build a AST for it. Then you can navigate the AST looking for variables. Alternatively, if you are processing JavaScript that might not be syntactically valid, you can use slimit's lexer.

Example using parser:

```
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor
from slimit import ast

js = '''
var x = 100;
var y = 200;
s = 'This is a string';
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    x--;
    y = y * 2;
}
'''

identifiers = set()    
tree = Parser().parse(js)
for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Identifier):
        identifiers.add(node.value)

>>> print "Found identifiers: {}".format(', '.join(identifiers))
Found identifiers: y, x, s, i
```

Or with just the lexer:

```
from slimit.lexer import Lexer

js = '''
var x = 100;
var y = 200;
s = 'This is a string';
while (var i=0; i<10; i++) {    // invalid while statement
    x--;
    y = y * 2;
}
'''

identifiers = set()
lexer = Lexer()

lexer.input(js)
for token in lexer:
    if token.type == 'ID':
        identifiers.add(token.value)

>>> print "Found identifiers: {}".format(', '.join(identifiers))
Found identifiers: y, x, s, i
```

Comment: This is great! I've been searching and searching for a python library for parsing js, but everyone seems to just be content with regex.

Answer (score -4):

If you use an IDE such as phpstorm, it can easily find variables for you. I don't see the use in programming something in Python to do this.

Comment: I have crores of files .It is not possible to open each file and see.

Comment: With phpstorm, you can do a `Ctrl + Shift + F` search to find all occurences of the text. `Ctrl + Shift + R` to do a Find Replace.